# rails-5 activerecord postgresql-9.6 enable_nestloop for a single sql query

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to turn on and turn off **postgresql enable_nestloop** for a single query in activerecord using raw SQL. Here is the command

```
 class Segment < ApplicationRecord
   def self.count_payload_kind

     s = "

       SET LOCAL enable_nestloop = off;

       SELECT count(*)
       FROM   segments s
       WHERE  s.payload @> '[{\"kind\":\"person\"}]';

       SET LOCAL enable_nestloop = on;
     "

     ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(s).to_a

   end
 end
```

When I call **ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(s).to_a**, it doesn't return any record and throws no error. However, it works correctly if i remove the 2 calls to **SET LOCAL enable_nestloop**

How can I turn enable_nestloop on and off for one query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my testing on Rails 4.2.6 and postgresql 9.5.4, wrapping the call in a transaction might work.

```
result = ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("SET LOCAL enable_nestloop = off;")
  r = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("
    SELECT count(*)
      FROM projects
     WHERE active;
  ")
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("SET LOCAL enable_nestloop = on;")
  r
end

result.values.flatten
=> ["1"]
```

SQL output

```
(4.3ms)  BEGIN
(6.8ms)  SET LOCAL enable_nestloop = off;
(98.3ms)
  SELECT count(*)
    FROM projects
   WHERE active;

(3.1ms)  SET LOCAL enable_nestloop = on;
(3.0ms)  COMMIT
```

Comment: Many thanks. It works. Tried awarding the bounty and it said I should wait for 7hours. I will award it once the time has elapsed.